# How to execute bunch of sql files at a time programmatically?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a scenario in which i have list of sql files in a directory. I need to loop through all the files and execute in mysql database. This can either be done using node.js or mysql itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: It can also be done in Bash, jus' sayin'... show what you've attempted thus far, and specify your _exact_ sticking point

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash command that should get you started:

```
for f in *.sql ; do mysql < "$f" ; done
```

Make sure you add your mysql connection info if it's not localhost.